# Selenium Webdriver not returning Javascript code

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hi I am new to Selenium Webdriver. I can successfully open a webpage and find elements on it.

In one case I have noted that there is a link on a page that becomes clickable after a while. In Firebug on the Script tab, I can see the code for the javascript that does the timer function.

But using Selenium Webdriver if I issue:

```
driver.PageSource
```

I cannot see the source code for the Javascript. Delaying for 30 seconds before requesting the source makes no difference. I have tried finding it with various By options using:

```
driver.FindElement
```

and so on, but it isnt there.

How does firebug manage to find and show the Javascript source code? Is there a way that I can coerce Selenium Webdriver to return all code referenced by the page?

Or is there a better approach?

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT---------------------

I tried the following in Firefox:

```
Dim Driver2 As IWebDriver = New Chrome.ChromeDriver
Driver2.Url = "http://mypage" 
Dim js As IJavaScriptExecutor = TryCast(Driver2, IJavaScriptExecutor)
Dim title As String = DirectCast(js.ExecuteScript("return JSON.stringify(window)"), String)
```

and I got

> Permission denied to access property 'toJSON'

I read that this wont work in firefox so I tried in Chrome, and got

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://mypage" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame

and from there no solutions because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153) its a security restriction, apparently you can't access an  with Javascript

I'm starting to think Im a bit out of my depth here.

Answer (score 0):

`PageSource` probably doesn't return an exact snapshot of the DOM & etc.

You can instead inspect javascript using `driver.executeScript()` but the burden of analyzing the return object may be discouraging.

Regardless - Here's a contrived example:

```
Object result = driver.executeScript("return JSON.stringify(window)");
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I tried this but came up against some issues, pls see the amended question.